# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientId' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular4-forms

After clicking on my object I change the component to another to update this object.
in this component for update I have a form that contains a `select` element with options which should be initialized with values from database (in method `OnInit`)

and I need to select by default from this list of values the value of my object

```
 <label>Catégorie Client:</label>
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="client.clientId" >
     <option></option>
     <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client.clientId">{{client.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

The problem is that the client can be null and I want in this case to show `<option></option>` as default value with empty value, but I got error

> cannot read null value

I have my object instantiated ...

Thanks for helping.

Comment: have you tried `client?.clientId`?  [value]="xxx"  it only supports string type, `[ngValue]="xxx"` supports any type

Comment: I tried ? but 

Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[(ngModel)]="client.clientId"` generates the error. `client` is not available here, you declared it in your `option`tags

Be aware `[value]="xxx"` supports string only, if your `clientId` is number, you'd better choose `[ngValue]="xxx"`

```
 <label>Catégorie Client:</label>
 <select 
   class="form-control" 
   [(ngModel)]="selectedClient" >
   <option></option>
   <option 
     *ngFor="let client of clients" 
     [ngValue]="client"
   >
   {{client.name}}
   </option>
 </select>
```

`selectedClient` needs to be initialized by one item of `clients`,

as [ConnorsFan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009922/connorsfan) mentioned, you can leave `selectedClient` as null, so nothing would be selected at the beginning.

Comment: but will not show the select if client is null , in my case I need to have possibilitty to select a value  or change it, to update my object <client>

Comment: @YKmar see my update, it's about the two way binding, client isn't declared yet

Comment: what about this ??? select id="idState" name="state" [ngModel]="user?.state"  
(ngModelChange)="user==null || user.state=$event">

Comment: @YKmar you don't need to do that, you can use `client` object directly

Comment: @haifzhan - If you change your last line to mention that `selectedClient` can also be initialized to `null`, and define the value of the first option as `null`, you get my upvote. :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thanks for your comment, it is a better choice if nothing selected at the beginning:)

Comment: True. The empty option is probably not necessary in that case (unless the OP wants to show something like `(Select a client)`, in which case the value of the option should be set to `null`).

Comment: yes it works fine for me (thank you so much) but I dont understand why !!!!!!
because its the same object with same value

Comment: when I pass object selectedClient in [ngValue] despite the value is not null it not select the option it get always default option